# Android Dialog Fragment with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is there good tutorial for DialogFragment with ViewPager?

I want to display a dialogbox which having  sliding tabs on it. like following image.

[image]

this tab window should appear inside Dialog box without action bar..Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: You  can just keep your activity and set a dialog theme for it in manifest file to make it appear as a dialog.

Comment: can you please explain it in detail..

Comment: Whithout action bar i dont know. My knowledge is from before actionbar time. Just give it a try.

Comment: You have to wait some hours or google for activity dialog theme meanwhile.

Comment: check this out: http://www.voidynullness.net/blog/2015/08/12/android-pagertabstrip-with-viewpager-and-appcompatactivity/